# EF Core 2.0 provider specific model configuration

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-model-builder

I am trying to upgrade an EF Core 1.x project to 2.0. In 1.x I was taking advantage of provider-specific extension methods (e.g. `ForSqlServerHasDefaultValueSql`/`ForSqliteHasDefaultValueSql` or `ForSqlServerHasColumnType`) but these seem to have been removed in 2.0.

Since each provider has its own flavor of SQL and capabilities, I need to be able to use slightly different setups or SQL strings per provider in `OnModelCreating`. For example to set a default value I might have:

```
modelBuilder<Foo>(b =>
{
    b.Property(x => x.CreateDate)
        .IsRequired()
        .ForSqlServerHasDefaultValueSql("getutcdate()")
        .ForSqliteHasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
}
```

How is this done in 2.0?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I couldn't find anything in the documentation (yet) but digging deep into the source, there is a comment in the logs of [commit 747c86556b2a21526973d462626e299b9bde7b91](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/commit/747c86556b2a21526973d462626e299b9bde7b91):

> ### Remove ForSqlServer... ForSqlite... methods for relational concepts
>
> Part of #7166
>
> Code can instead use
>
> ```
> if (Database.IsSqlServer())
> {
>     modelBuilder.HasColumnName("MySqlServerName");
> }
> ```

Therefore the snippet in the question would translate to:

```
modelBuilder<Foo>(b =>
{
    b.Property(x => x.CreateDate)
        .IsRequired();

    if (Database.IsSqlServer())
        b.Property(x => x.CreateDate).HasDefaultValueSql("getutcdate()");

    if (Database.IsSqlite())
        b.Property(x => x.CreateDate).HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
}
```

---

Kudos to @IvanStoev for pointing me to [the 1.x to 2.0 upgrade documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/1x-2x-upgrade). Somehow my Google-fu was failing me today. On this page it clearly shows what to do:

> Instead of using methods like `ForSqlServerToTable`, extension methods
>   are now available to write conditional code based on the current
>   provider in use. For example:
>
> ```
> modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable(
>     Database.IsSqlServer() ? "SqlServerName" : "OtherName");
> ```

Comment: Here is a link to the (sort of) documentation - **EF Core relational metadata API changes** topic from [Upgrading applications from previous versions to EF Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/1x-2x-upgrade)

Comment: @IvanStoev That's the page I was hoping would exist. Thank you!