# EF Core 2 Provider specific HasDefaultValueSql

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use my `DbContext` with multiple providers. So far everything works okay, except when using `HasDefaultValueSql()`.

What I am trying to do is to have a property `AuditTimestamp` that has the current time when added (and saved) on the `dbContext`. This can easily be done using something like this that works for the SQL Server provider

```
modelBuilder
   .Entity(entityType.ClrType)
   .Property(nameof(AuditBase.AuditTimestamp))
   .HasDefaultValueSql("SYSUTCDATETIME()");
```

But when trying to use the same `dbContext` with SqLite provider, it doesn't work since `SYSUTCDATETIME` isn't a valid SQL function in SqLite.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088952/ef-core-2-0-provider-specific-model-configuration) I tried to do

```
modelBuilder
   .Entity(entityType.ClrType)
   .Property(nameof(AuditBase.AuditTimestamp))
   .HasDefaultValueSql(Database.IsSqlite() ? "DATETIME('now')" : "SYSUTCDATETIME()");
```

But it generates this in the migrations

```
b.Property<DateTime>("AuditTimestamp")
   .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
   .HasDefaultValueSql("SYSUTCDATETIME()");
```

because I use a SQL Server connection string when generating the migrations. This implies that I need different sets of migrations based on what provider I use which shouldn't be the case.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52365060/entity-framework-core-2-1-multiple-providers) it is possible to have provider specific configurations in the migration files but the example is based on auto generated Id column and I don't know how to apply this to `HasDefaultValueSql()`

From [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10193) I found that this might work

```
HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
```

But I would like a more general solution for when you have two (or more) providers that don't share same SQL function names.

The providers I use is SQL Server for production and SqLite for unit testing. EF Core is version 2.2

Comment: Here is the EF Core designers vision - [Migrations with Multiple Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

Comment: @IvanStoev, could you maybe give an answer that explains how to use annotations from your link?

Comment: Does CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and SYSUTCDATETIME deliver the same values?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems the prescribled way is to edit migrations by hand (as you pointed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52365060/entity-framework-core-2-1-multiple-providers) and Ivan suggests in the comments to your question)
I do however believe there's a way to override actual SQL code generation on the execution stage.

The main thing you want to look at will be the [`MigrationsSqlGenerator`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/v2.2.8/src/EFCore.Relational/Migrations/MigrationsSqlGenerator.cs) class. It builds SQL for each type of migration commands that needs to be run. Therefore in your case overriding a `DefaultValue` will probably suffice:

```cs
 public class CustomMigrationsSqlGenerator : MigrationsSqlGenerator
    {
        public CustomMigration(MigrationsSqlGeneratorDependencies dependencies) : base(dependencies)
        {
        }

        /// <param name="defaultValue">The default value for the column.</param>
        /// <param name="defaultValueSql">The SQL expression to use for the column's default constraint.</param>
        /// <param name="builder"></param>        
        /// <see cref="https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/v2.2.8/src/EFCore.Relational/Migrations/MigrationsSqlGenerator.cs#L1407"/>
        protected override void DefaultValue(object defaultValue, string defaultValueSql, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
        {
            Debugger.Launch();
            if (defaultValueSql != null) // I assume you only want to adapt specific values rather than whole type
            {
                if (Dependencies.SqlGenerationHelper is SqliteSqlGenerationHelper)
                { 
                builder
                    .Append(" DEFAULT (") 
                    .Append(defaultValueSql) //replace with your specific provider logic
                    .Append(")");
                    return;
                } else if (Dependencies.SqlGenerationHelper is SqlServerSqlGenerationHelper)
                {
                    builder
                        .Append(" DEFAULT (") 
                        .Append(defaultValueSql) //replace with your specific provider logic
                        .Append(")");
                    return;
                }
            }
            //fall back to default implementation
            base.DefaultValue(defaultValue, defaultValueSql, builder);
        }
    }
```

now that we've got a custom migration generator, we need to replace EF's default implementation:

```cs
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseWhateverDbProviderForMigrations();
optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<IMigrationsSqlGenerator, CustomMigrationsSqlGenerator>();
var context = new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
```

I don't know enough on how you bootstrap the DbContext into your application and how you invoke the migrations, but assuming you are calling it from Package Manager console, the [following trick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation) will allow you to hijack the control:

```cs
 public class MigrationStartup: IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
    {
        public MyDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseWhateverDbProviderForMigrations();
            optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<IMigrationsSqlGenerator, CustomMigration>(); // this is the important bit

            return new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
```

This approach can be extended to other types of SQL generated, by simply providing a respective override.

**One thing to note**: between EF 2.2 and EF 3 the `DefaultValue()` method signature has changed. So I guess I should warn you this is more of a hack and comes with certain support implications.

Comment: I have not tried your approach but even if it works it seems to be a lot of work for something that the framework should be able to handle in a simpler way.